# Issue with javascript object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to make a skribbl replica for my friends. To do so, I'm using javascript and a websocket. The drawing canvas needs to be shared so I'm sending the data to the server to redraw them on the others canvas. To do so I used a function:

```
function newDrawing(data){  
        context.beginPath();
        context.lineTo(data.x, data.y);
        context.moveTo(data.x, data.y);
        context.stroke();
       }
    }
```

I save the values using:

```
let data={
            x: e.clientX-this.offsetLeft,
            y: e.clientY-this.offsetTop
}
```

But I'm not getting a straight line. My understanding is that context.lineTo(data.x, data.y); and context.moveTo(data.x, data.y); starts and end at the same point and I dont know how to fix that as I'm fairly new to this language. Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: What are the endpoints of the straight line? I understand one is (data.x, data.y)

Comment: I'm using a mousedown and mouse up event to draw a line ( not especially straight) and sending them to a websocket server. Im saving the position using :

let data={
            x: e.clientX-this.offsetLeft,
            y: e.clientY-this.offsetTop
}

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might come from the parameters you pass to your function newDrawing and how you use them
for instance right now it seems that you are calling it like so :
newDrawing({x:10,y:10});
which means that you're only passing one point as an argument
so in terms you draw the same point

you also inverted moveTo and lineTo.

so you would get the following code at the end :

```js
let ctx = can.getContext("2d");

const newDrawing = (data) => {  
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = "5";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
        ctx.moveTo(data.x, data.y);
        ctx.lineTo(data.x2, data.y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    
newDrawing({x:10,y:10,x2:100,y2:10});
```

```html
<canvas id=can height=200 width=300 ></canvas>
```

But what you're looking for precisely looks more like this :

```js
let ctx = can.getContext("2d");
let prev = undefined;

const newDrawing = (data) => {  
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = "5";
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
        ctx.moveTo(data.x, data.y);
        ctx.lineTo(data.x2, data.y2);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    
const createAndDraw = ev =>{
if(!prev) prev={x:ev.clientX,y:ev.clientY};
newDrawing({x:prev.x,y:prev.y,x2:ev.clientX,y2:ev.clientY});
  prev={x:ev.clientX,y:ev.clientY};
}

can.addEventListener("mousemove", createAndDraw);
```

```html
<canvas id=can height=200 width=300 ></canvas>
```

Comment: This helped me a lot ! Isse fixed, thanks